# to disable required field validator

Tags: javascript

this is my javascript code here i  am unable to disable the `textbox(id="due_Date")` when i get the zero or negative amount in text feild `(id="subtotal_input")`...any help would be appreciated....

```
  <script>
    window.onload = function() 
    {
       document.getElementById('subtotal_input').onchange = disablefield;
       document.getElementById('phone_no').onchange = disablefield;
       document.getElementById('phone_yes').onchange = disablefield;
     }

     function disablefield()
     {
         if ( document.getElementById('subtotal_input').value <= 0 )
         {
         document.getElementById('due_Date').value = '';
         document.getElementById('due_Date').disabled = true
         }


         if ( document.getElementById('phone_no').checked == true )
         {
         document.getElementById('ReturnDate').value = '';
         document.getElementById('ReturnDate').disabled = true}
         else if (document.getElementById('phone_yes').checked == true ){
         document.getElementById('ReturnDate').disabled = false;
         }

    }
```

Comment: The field isn't disable, event if you click somewhere after a change ?

Comment: Can you try readonly for this?

Comment: Did you used server control? If so you need to use server tags instead direct id's. Provide your HTML markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ValidatorEnable(validator, enable)` to enable or disable a validator.

You can use something like this:

```
objValidator = document.getElementById("<%=YourRequiredValidatorID.ClientID %>");
objValidator.enabled = true; //'true' if you want to enable else 'false'
ValidatorUpdateDisplay(objValidator);
```

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: thanks sir for your reply bt the problem is now fixed as i made some syntax mistakes there and scope maistakes were there too....thanx alot .....